# Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() is always Empty

Tags: powershell

I am executing `auditpol /get /category:*` as another user, but I always get an empty result on `$GetProcessResult`. `Auditpol` requires administrative privileges before it can be ran. I have found similar questions, and the recommendations I got were to

- get the `standardoutput` and `StandardError` from different threads
- subscribe to the `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` events, to avoid using extra threads

Can you provide examples of the solutions above?

I am very new to PowerShell, and still learning.

Here is the code:

---

```
#Get UserB credential
$Credential = Get-Credential garuwindows\cit
#Use System.Diagnostics to start the process as UserB
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

#With FileName we're basically telling powershell to run another powershell process
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
$ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$ProcessInfo.Verb = "runas"
#CreateNoWindow helps avoiding a second window to appear whilst the process runs

#Note the line below contains the Working Directory where the script will start from
$ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = $env:windir
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

#The line below is basically the command you want to run and it's passed as text, as an argument
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "auditpol /get /category:*"

#The next 3 lines are the credential for UserB, as you can see, we can't just pass $Credential
$ProcessInfo.Username = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().username
$ProcessInfo.Domain = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
$ProcessInfo.Password = $Credential.Password

#Finally start the process and wait for it to finish
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo 
$Process.Start() | Out-Null 

$Process.WaitForExit() 

#Grab the output
$GetProcessResult = $Process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()

#Print the Job results
$GetProcessResult
```

Comment: Keep in mind that providing admin credentials is not equivalent to running elevated.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart The "runas" verb will elevate the process so that shouldn't be the problem. @Edgar I suspect stdout is discarded but I'm not sure why. On a side note, why do you start another PS instance just to call auditpol? Why not use `$ProcessInfo.FileName = "auditpol.exe"`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Get UserB credential
$Credential = Get-Credential garuwindows\cit
#Use System.Diagnostics to start the process as UserB
$ProcessInfo = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo

#With FileName we're basically telling powershell to run another powershell process
$ProcessInfo.FileName = "powershell.exe"
$ProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = $true
$ProcessInfo.Verb = "runas"
#CreateNoWindow helps avoiding a second window to appear whilst the process runs

#Note the line below contains the Working Directory where the script will start from
$ProcessInfo.WorkingDirectory = $env:windir
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError = $true 
$ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = $true 
$ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = $false

#The line below is basically the command you want to run and it's passed as text, as an argument
$ProcessInfo.Arguments = "auditpol /get /category:*"

#The next 3 lines are the credential for UserB, as you can see, we can't just pass $Credential
$ProcessInfo.Username = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().username
$ProcessInfo.Domain = $Credential.GetNetworkCredential().Domain
$ProcessInfo.Password = $Credential.Password

#Finally start the process and wait for it to finish
$Process.StartInfo = $ProcessInfo 
$Process.Start() | Out-Null 

#Grab the output
$GetProcessResult = $process.standardoutput.readtoend()
$GetProcessResult

$Process.WaitForExit()
```

You should wait the process for exit after you have received the output, otherwise it will redirect no data.